# A TreeCellEditor for Multiple Node Editing

Tags: java, jtree

Can someone show an example of a TreeCellEditor that can update multiple nodes on a single edit? From what I can tell, `GetCellEditorValue()` will only update a single node.

My editor currently takes in the selected Nodes, compares them and displays differing values as  while displaying the other values that the nodes have in common.

My Constructor which initializes "myDevice".

```
    public DeviceEditor(Collection<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodes) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    System.out.println("CREATING NEW EDITOR \n");
    this.nodes = nodes;
    ObjectMatcher matcher = new ObjectMatcher();
    try {
        myDevice = matcher.match(nodes, DefaultDevice.CREATE_MULTIVALUE_DEFAULTDEVICE(), new DefaultDevice());
        //System.out.println("Device= " + myDevice.getAddress() + " " + myDevice.getHostName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    initComponents();

}
```

The methods of TreeCellEditor

```
@Override
public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree jtree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
   // this.tree = jtree;
    return this;

}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    //This value is what is populated into the JTree
    return this.myDevice;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject eo) {
    //should be true only if it's a leaf. 
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject eo) {
    //Don't Select
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    try {
        System.out.println("\n Cell Editing Stopped");
        //update myDevice
        if (!this.addressField.getText().equals(DefaultDevice.MULTIVALUE)) {
            myDevice.setAddress(this.addressField.getText());
        }
        myDevice.setDeviceType(this.deviceTypeField.getText());
        myDevice.setLocation(this.locationField.getText());
        myDevice.setSerialNumber(this.serialField.getText());
        myDevice.setUser(this.userField.getText());
        myDevice.setPassword(new String(this.passwordField.getPassword()));
        myDevice.setVendor(this.vendorField.getText());
        myDevice.setModel(this.modelField.getText());
        myDevice.setOS(this.osField.getText());
        myDevice.setDescription(this.descriptionField.getText());
        myDevice.setVersion(this.versionField.getText());
        myDevice.setDeviceType(this.deviceTypeField.getText());
        myDevice.setDisplayHostName(this.hostNameCheckBox.isSelected());
        myDevice.setDisplayIPV4Address(this.ipV4checkBox.isSelected());
        myDevice.setDisplayIPV6Address(this.ipV6CheckBox.isSelected());

        DeviceEditor.UPDATE_DEVICES(nodes, myDevice);
        return true;
    } catch (IPConverter.InvalidIPException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        return false;
    }

}
```